# How to hide my HTML drop-down menu correctly?

Tags: javascript, css

I made a drop-down menu consisting of a HTML input/button and some more buttons as drop-down menu items. The menu is shown as soon as hovered over the main button

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="dropdown-wifi" class="extended-button" onclick="showDropDown()">Available WiFi Hot Spots</button>
    <div id="ssid-dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <!-- drop-down menu items dynamically created by JavaScript -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the hover event in CSS:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

The JavaScript code that hides and later 'should' show again:

```
function showDropDown() {
    document.getElementById("ssid-dropdown").style.display = 'block';
}

function hideDropDown() {
    document.getElementById("ssid-dropdown").style.display = 'none';
}
```

Now, the drop-down menu is properly shown as soon as I hover over the main button. But when selecting an item, I call `hideDropDown()` to hide the menu even if not hovered outside of the items.

I notified that as soon as the `hideDropDown()` function is called, the following is added in the CSS window of Chrome's debug windows:

```
element.style {
    display: none;
}
```

I guess, that is a kind of CSS generated because my JavaScript function call of `hideDropDown()`. However, as soon as this `element.stlye` is occuring, the hovering/show of the drop-down menu doesn't work anymore.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like multiple things are present here. Can you show us a [mcve] that might help to repro this issue?

Comment: You can set css priority. like .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block !important;
}

Comment: you could also use visibility property to my best of knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create class  with name `hide` and add next css:

```
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

Add or remove this class. This way is very simple

Answer (score 0):

hello to my dear friend you can simply just use jquery like this :

`$(".dropdown").show()` OR `$(".dropdown").hide()`